# No puedo descargar un archivo pdf encima del root php

Tags: php, pdf

Hola a todos estoy tratando de descargar un pdf usando php pero me salta el siguiente error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/u232864974/public_html/partials/headers.php:115) in /home/u232864974/public_html/verdetalle.php on line 141

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/4544545/public_html/partials/headers.php:115) in /home/4544545/public_html/verdetalle.php on line 144
%PDF-1.4 %äüöß 2 0 obj <> stream x��[ˎ�6��Wx=@U,Y~���m �]��Yf5��*   n6��#�IQ���t���V�m=�8<$��j���|oZ�o0�g�������������t�ul��\��u�uh���w|�?��ia��]�__~��W�,�7��P��׫i�I���^^?^�`S3��:7?7?��1����?n�����Z{7�ow���ֵ���
```

etcetera

Y este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
<table class="table-bordered table-striped">       
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Tus subidas...<label><a href="index.php">upload new files...</a></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>File Name</td>
    <td>File Type</td>
    <td>File Size(KB)</td>
    <td>View</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM uploads";
              $query = $db->prepare($sql);
 //$result->bindparam(':orden_de_compra', $orden_de_compra);

$query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $dir; ?>facturas/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
            <td>
                <?
            $content = $dir . 'facturas/' . $row['file'];

  header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile($content);
                ?>
            </td>        

        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: con que libreria lo estas haciendo?

Comment: No estoy utilizando librerias pense que se podia hacer algo con file get contents, lo que quiero es que se descargue el pdf al dar click en el link, el problems es que tengo mis archivos por encima del root lo  ual no permite un acceso directo por url

Comment: intentalo con una libreria es mucho mas sencillo yo cuando lo hago lo hago con dompdf

Comment: Se puede imprimir sobre la misma pagina  multiples pdf aunque tenga contenido html en el? que libreria recomiendas que pueda utilizar con cualquier proposito?

Comment: si claro como te dije en el comentario de arriba dompdf

Comment: Ya estoy muy ciego jeje, gracias deja intentarlo

Comment: ok que tengas suerte

Comment: Es para html no? pero yo tengo mi pdf en formato .pdf no ocupo convertirlo solo descargarlo, la tabla que aparece en mi codifo es solo para mostrar las celdas donde iran los links de descarga, mis archivos estan en el servidor

Comment: ah no es para php no pense que los tenias en el servidor

Comment: tienes que agregar en el header del html `header("Content-type:application/pdf");`

Answer (score 1):

Cuando cargas un PDF desde PHP para enviar a la salida (pantalla) tienes que asegurarte de no enviar ningún carácter (aunque sea un espacio) previamente. Elimina los `<td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>` y carga únicamente el archivo PDF.

Otra solución es guardar el PDF como archivo y mostrar un enlace hacia él.

Espero haberte servido de ayuda

Comment: Asi lo resolvi cree un php especifico sin contenido html

Answer (score 1):

Asi lo resolvi cree un archivo php sin contenido html:

```
<?php
include_once 'resource/session.php';
include 'resource/Dir.php';

error_reporting (0);
          if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
              if($_SESSION['salida_materiales'] == 1 )
{

include_once 'resource/Database.php';

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

$id = $_GET['id'];



       $sql = "select file from uploads where id = :id "; 
$result = $db->prepare($sql); 
$result->bindparam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$result->execute();
$file_name = $result->fetchColumn(); 
$ubicacion = $dir . 'facturas/' . $file_name;  



  header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='$file_name'");

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile($ubicacion);




}




              }
          }

else{
    echo "No has iniciado sesion";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Si no he entendido mal, el pdf ya esta creado y lo que quieres es que se pueda descargar, ¿verdad?. Lo unico que tienes que hacer es un anchor con el link de la ruta y el nombre del pdf, es decir, /facturas/*nombrepdf.pdf*. Comprueba que la ruta sea la correcta y por supuesto los permisos que tiene el directorio

Comment: Ese es el problema mis archivos pdf estaran por encima del public debido a que quiero incrementar su seguridad, entonces no puedo abrirlos directamente con la url

Comment: por favor mira como responder  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: aunque tú tengas tu directorio fuera de públic el problema que planteas seguiría siendo el mismo, que alguien te liste los archivos de ese directorio y sustraiga documentación. El problema no es donde pongas los documentos, si no quién los puede ver. Con el código que vemos aquí la seguridad es poca, pero hay un montón de artículos sobre permisos y cambios en htacces para denegar el listado. Un ejemplo es la opción IndexIgnore *.php. te recomiendo que antes de acceder a esos recursos utilices algún tipo de validación de que el token del usuario es válido para realizar ese tipo de acción